# frames skipped in openGL

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

I have a rather simple piece of openGL code that draws 2D images as quads (well, as triangles, but the result is the same):

```
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC); 

GLuint texture; 

glGenTextures(1, &texture); 
glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); 

glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1); 
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); 
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT); 
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); 
glTexEnvf (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE); 
glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, RasterSize.width, RasterSize.height, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pRaster); 

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture); 

glBegin( GL_TRIANGLE_FAN ); 

glTexCoord2d(0.0,0.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,+1.0); 
glTexCoord2d(1.0,0.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,+1.0); 
glTexCoord2d(1.0,1.0); glVertex2d(+1.0,-1.0); 
glTexCoord2d(0.0,1.0); glVertex2d(-1.0,-1.0); 

glEnd(); 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0); 
glDeleteTextures(1, &texture); 
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 

SwapBuffers(hDC); 
wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
```

I have multiple windows, and each one can run this code (multithreaded) with some raster to draw. Although the application usually sets the framerate, I'm interested in maximal framerate for the purpose of performance.

I should note that when I initialized the window for the first time (when the HGLRC was created, which is cached vs the HWND), I used the SwapInterval extension to turn-off V-Sync.

On some cards (Nvidia) everything behaves as expected. On another card, however, skipping of frames can be noticed. Frames are loaded and "finish rendering", i.e. the above method returns, but only some actually appear on screen. With the VSync on, framerate is much slower and yet the a similar behavior appears.

I also tried calls to glFlush() and glFinish, which didn't help.

I would appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: is this code in your WM_PAINT handler?

Comment: it's not connected (directly) to any windows event - way down the food-chain :)

Comment: You realise disabling v_sync will not improve ~performance~, all it does is prevent your program from waiting for the v_sync to actually swap frame buffers.

Comment: @thecoshman: although not true for this example, FPS /is/ higher with vsync off, isn't it?

Comment: glTexImage2D is slow operation. Maybe shouldn't do it in frame loop.

Comment: @uv_: With vsync off, _rendered frames per seconds_ will be higher, but if your display is set to 60 Hz it will be physically impossible to see more that 60 _real frames per seconds_. So your 3000 or so rendered FPS will be mostly invisible.

Comment: @rodrigo: I get that, but my real fps (when frames are skipped) is definitely lower than the screen's refresh rate

Comment: @rodrigo: screen tearing